# How can I change multiple <SPAN> 's backgroundColor at random intervals?

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, html

So I have multiple spans like this:

```
<span unselectable="on" 
    onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffcc99';"
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#a8c0f0';"
    onclick="javascript stuff" 
    style="-webkit-user-select:none;
        -moz-user-select:none;
        display: inline-block; 
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: arial; 
        background: #a8c0f0;
        padding-top:9px;
        padding-bottom:9px;
        padding-right:9px;
        padding-left:9px;">
    My Span
</span>
```

I'd like them to twinkle/blink if you will, with each changing background colors from their normal color state to another color I'll define for just about .5 to 1 second and then back to their normal color.

But I would like them all to fire at random times so it doesn't look like a pattern. Just occasional lazy twinkles. Like once every 8-15 seconds.

I noticed "onload" doesn't work with SPANs so I'm not sure how I would do it.

Comment: Say I have 40 spans I want to flicker. I would like each to start flickering randomly. The flicker duration would be fixed(ex 800ms). But the interval between each fixed flicker (speaking about a single span here) would be random between say 8 and 20 seconds. This way they aren't all going off at the same time. Nor in a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get a reference to all `span` elements.
- Store their original background color with `style.backgroundColor`.
- Generate a random number of seconds.
- Use `setInterval()` with a `1000` interval.
- Each interval, decrement the random number of seconds. When it is 0, change the background color. Use a new `setTimeout()` to restore the original color.
- Generate a new random number of seconds and repeat.

Comment: Some nice food for thought. Trying something different though.